# How to edit rows that have duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not very experienced with SQL. I need to manually edit the rows in a table [`TABLE_A`] that have the equal values in [`COLUMN_1`] and [`COLUMN_2`]. I already know how to filter the Edit view for a table, I just need the right query.

Example:

```
   COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3
    A       100       3
    C       354       2
    A       999       3
    A       100       1
    C       255       1
    B       600       5
    B       600       5
    B       600       7
```

I would need the query to return rows 1, 4, 6, 7, and 8. So it should return a table like this:

```
   COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3
    A       100       3
    A       100       1
    B       600       5
    B       600       5
    B       600       7
```

I tried googling and this is the closest thing I could get so this is what I am doing right now but it's not what I need.

```
SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
  FROM TABLE_A
 GROUP BY COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

The problem with that query is that it doesn't return each individual line. It returns something like this:

```
   COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 TotalCount
    A       100        2
    B       600        3
```

Comment: EDIT: Removed the acutal names of my tables and replaced them with generic stuff like COLUMN_1, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [Window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) -

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Column_1, 
            Column_2, 
            Column_3, 
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Column_1, Column_2) AS TotalDupes
    FROM    Table_A
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE   TotalDupes > 1
```